# Prevent User Going Back to Login Page If Already Logged In

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I just added a login mechanism using Spring Security, my configuration looks like this:

```
@Override  
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
            
  http                              
  .authorizeRequests()  
      .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")  
   .and()
  .formLogin()
   .loginPage("/login")
  .and()  
  .httpBasic()  
  .and()  
  .logout()  

  .logoutSuccessUrl("/")  
  ;  
  
  // Disabled to allow file upload.
  http
    .csrf().disable();
  
  
}
```

My only problem is that when the user is logged in, they can visit the endpoint `/login` again and he could login and get another session ID. I'm using the default configuration for Security as you can see, I don't have a custom login page and no controller for handling `/login` requests. Is there a way to solve this issue in my case?

Comment: So you mean you want the user after he login will direct him another page yes?.
if that your problem you can use in configuration after ".loginPage().defaultSuccessUrl("/home")

Comment: @BASSAMALHARBI I want to prevent the user from visiting /login again when he is already logged in

Comment: Ok i get it now, you may check this. https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-login-page-if-already-logged-in